# Nginx redirection different with IP behavior on 2 different machine

Tags: linux, nginx, redhat

**context**

I have 2 Linux Red Hat machines hosting nginx server. Nginx server is working with below config:

nginx config server 1

```
user1@server1:/etc/nginx/conf.d $ cat docgen_react.conf
server{
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name url1.com;
        root /home/user1/gru/documentgenerator/react_client/build;
        index index.html index.htm;
}
```

nginx config server 2

```
user2@server2:/etc/nginx/conf.d $  cat docgen_react.conf
server{
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name url2.com;
        root /export/home/user2/gru/documentgenerator/react_client/build;
        index index.html index.htm;
}
```

**current behavior**

- If I am navigating to [www.url1.com](http://www.url1.com), it points properly to the webpage I
  want to reach hosted on server 1
- If I am navigating to [www.url2.com](http://www.url2.com),
  it points properly to the webpage I want to reach hosted on server 2
- If I am navigating to ip server 1, it points properly to the webpage I
  want to reach hosted on server1 (same  as [www.url1.com](http://www.url1.com))
- **If I am navigating to ip server 2, I point to web page located on /usr/share/doc/HTML/en-US/index.html (not same as [www.url2.com](http://www.url2.com))**

**expected behavior**

- If I am navigating to [www.url1.com](http://www.url1.com), it points properly to the webpage I
  want to reach hosted on server 1
- If I am navigating to [www.url2.com](http://www.url2.com),
  it points properly to the webpage I want to reach hosted on server 2
- If I am navigating to ip server 1, it points properly to the webpage I
  want to reach hosted on server1 (same  as [www.url1.com](http://www.url1.com))
- **If I am navigating to ip server 2, it points properly to the webpage I
  want to reach hosted on server2 (same as [www.url2.com](http://www.url2.com))**

To sum-up if I use IP address I want to reach the same page as if I am navigating via [www.url2.com](http://www.url2.com)

Comment: please share content of `nginx.conf` file on both servers,

Comment: Thanks for your question, I was only focusing on /etc/nginx/conf.d and as I am not familiar I was not aware that there was a config above. I then compare the server1 vs server2 config and saw the difference I will detail below. Thanks @ThanhNguyenVan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @ThanhNguyenVan's comment, I found the solution.

I was only focusing on /etc/nginx/conf.d and as I am not familiar with nginx I was not aware that there was a config above i.e /etc/nginx/nginx.conf. I then compare the server1 vs server2 config and saw the difference.

[image]

After commenting that part below it worked like charm:

```
  server {
      listen       80 default_server;
      listen       [::]:80 default_server;
      server_name  _;
      root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

      # Load configuration files for the default server block.
      include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

      location / {
      }

      error_page 404 /404.html;
          location = /40x.html {
      }

      error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
          location = /50x.html {
      }
  }
```